# create sum, avg and min of file

Tags: bash, scripts

I have this homework question:

> create function agg, first argument is filename, second will be sum, avg or min. script will compute sum, average or minimum (dependig on 2. argument) from the numbers in the file (1. arg.). Consider only one column file, one number per line.

I came up with this function:

```
agg(){

    cat $1 | awk '{sum+=$1} END{print "sum of first column = "sum}'
    cat $1 | awk '{sum+=$1} END { print "Average = ",sum/NR}'
    cat $1 | awk 'min=="" || $1 < min {min=$1} END{ print "min="min}'

}
agg y
```

my script works fine but without the arguments. How can I incorporate the arguments? thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use case here:

```
case "$2" in
  sum) awk '{sum+=$1} END{print "sum of first column = "sum}' "$1";;
  avg) awk '{sum+=$1} END { print "Average = ",sum/NR}' "$1";;
  min) awk 'min=="" || $1 < min {min=$1} END{ print "min="min}' "$1";;
esac
```

Comment: Hey Wayne, you made my day :) Case did the job :) thanks!!!

Comment: why do you need the "$1" at the end of the commands?

Comment: that's a shortcut for `cat $1 |`. This way the `awk` command opens the file itself and does not read the content from `STDIN`, like it would using `cat`