# how can i find the average of data in a column in a txt file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I need to write a script that can find the average of numbers in a column and then print out the value when run. I am quite new to Linux commands, and I've tried my best, but I don't even know how to begin. I thought I need to make a counter somehow and use the awk command, but I don't know how to make it read the data in the column or to then divide over the number of entries. it might sound simple to most, but I started using Linux 2 days ago so I'm quite lost and would appreciate any help.

Comment: You can do this with LibreOffice Spreadsheet (an alternative software of Microsoft Excel). Is there any particular reason you are trying to use the command line to calculate average of numbers? Are you using any particular language? What exactly are you trying to do? Please edit the question and add more information.

Comment: This sounds like an elementary homework exercise - there are many examples, even here on AskUbuntu ex. [create sum, avg and min of file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/640437/create-sum-avg-and-min-of-file)

Comment: python: read lines of file, split lines, make column you need to count a float or inti, print sum and done :)  Your q is a simple coding question  ;-)

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers.

Answer (score 4):

##### Like this:

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

```
$ awk '
    {count+=$1}
    END{print count/NR}
' file
```

##### Output

```
3.5
```

##### Explanations

| Operator | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `{}` | awk operation/expression/code |
| `count` | a random variable |
| `+=$1` | + value of column1 increment |
| `END` or `true condition` | code to run... at the `END` or on `true condition`. `awk` is all about `true{expr}` like `1{print}` |
| `count/NR` | simple arithmetic division |
| `NR` | number of the current/last line: `N`umber of `R`ecords |

Comment: There was a backtick left open and was breaking the formatting. ;)

Comment: Reported [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388490/missing-a-backtick-from-markdown-table-in-preview-was-well-rendered-but-not-ser)